# Integrating swagger-node in sails existing app to generate dynamic documentaiton

Tags: node.js, sails.js, swagger, swagger-ui, documentation-generation

I have an existing Sails app and I want to generate the API documentation dynamically using swagger-node .Until now what ever resources I went through about swagger-node ,what I am able to get is that you can ether create a swagger app from scratch using `swagger project create <project Name>`or you can write the yaml file manually to make the documentation .
So just wanted to know is there a way to get the documentation of my exiting sails app dynamical using swagger

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [sails-swagger hook](https://github.com/langateam/sails-swagger) is helpful.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.